# How to set frame encoding method as CABAC in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, lossless

I'm trying to encode video frames into H264 format using ffmpeg in C. While configuring the encoder properties I don't see how to set the frame encoding method as CABAC (lossless). Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `coder_type` value of the encoder's context to `FF_CODER_TYPE_AC`.